# Ошибка при подключении к mysql БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, ubuntu, pdo

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through
 socket/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (11)`

Нашел один ответ именно по 11 ошибке. Вроде как не верные данные для подключения, но все правильно указано, работает. Иногда пишется в мои лог-файлы эта ошибка.

Использую таблицы MyISAM, знаю, что InnoDB блокируют только строку, а не всю таблицу, в отличии от 1-го типа, но там вроде ограничение по количеству строк читал когда-то и по выборке быстрее 1-й тип таблиц.

my.cnf:

```
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 nice            = 0

    [mysqld]
    user            = mysql
    pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
    port            = 3306
    basedir         = /usr
    datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
    tmpdir          = /tmp
    lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
    skip-external-locking

    bind-address            = 127.0.0.1

    Fine Tuning
    #
    key_buffer              = 8192M
    max_allowed_packet      = 16M
    thread_stack            = 192K
    thread_cache_size       = 64
    # This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
    # the first time they are touched
    myisam-recover         = BACKUP
    max_connections        = 1000
    #table_cache            = 64
    table_cache             = 1024
    #thread_concurrency     = 10
    #
    # Query Cache Configuration
    #
    query_cache_limit       = 2M
    query_cache_size        = 128M
    #query_cache_type        = 1
```

Comment: А в логах  /var/log/mysql/error.log ничего интересного нет? Если там логов нет, поищите их в каталоге данных.

Comment: У вас эта ошибка сейчас постоянно или она возникает время от времени?

Comment: В логах  /var/log/mysql/error.log пусто  
Не, не всегда эта ошибка

Что-то в этом редакторе не работает перенос строк, не 2 пробела, не <br/>

Comment: Вот еще что сделайте, посмотрите максимальное количество соединений show variables like 'max_connections'; и максимально достигнутое show status like 'Max_used_connections'; - не было ситуаций, когда вы подходили к максимальному количеству соединений? 11 - это скорее всего у вас сервер не тянет нагрузку, но это нужно больше информации о вашем сервере, нагрузке, что в my.cnf, вообще хорошо бы за сервером понаблюдать.

Comment: `max_connections` 1000 вместо 100 поставил, выделил 8 гб ОЗУ для буфера. Сейчас хоть БД не виснет и нет ошибок о том, что много соединений.

Comment: Ой, зря... каждое соединение потребляет память, достигнете потолка - может не хватить - надо считать по буферам, сколько максимум памяти может потреблять соединение. Плюс, не должна MySQL так реагировать при достижении потолка соединений - отлуп должна давать, штатаный и который идет в логи. Тут что-то хитрее мне кажется, ну и 1000 - это перебор, хотя бы 150 для начала, а вообще посчитать бы надо.

Comment: Та вот некогда, все на лету, не ожидали такого наплыва, памяти 32 Гб ОЗУ и 8 Гб swap-раздел, сам сервер сильно не напрягается. Кстати вот с 2-х ночи и по сейчас, смотрю — ошибок нет...

Comment: Конфиг my.cnf надо смотреть, добавите его в вопрос? Дело в том, что MySQL сама памяти не возьмет - ей выделять надо, а чтобы выделять надо знать какие преимущественно таблицы используете (MyISAM, InnoDB, может что-то другое), какие преимущественно запросы. По умолчанию MySQL не оптимизирована под такие мощные сервера - она будет жаться на 200Мб и не возьмет память, даже если её рядом навалом.

Comment: Добавил, заменил решетки на //, т.к. редактор показывает как заголовки и как код не форматируется почему-то `должно же так быть`

Comment: Используйте фигурные скобки для форматирования - будет блок кода

Comment: Опишите немного свой свервис - запросы в основном на запись, на чтение? Или нет такой информации? Используются ли тяжелые, долговыполняющиеся запросы? На сервере, еще кто-то кроме MySQL есть?

Comment: (http://vkonmillion.com) - этот адрес на сервере wix, а вот у нас уже на сервере (http://my.vkonmillion.com) - как бы маркетинг, подписчики в вк.  Идет На вставку много, каждый переход по реф ссылке, если переход за сегодня уникальный по IP по данной ссылке — это вот 100 000 вставлено за сегодня. И в кабинете, если человек не оплачен, раз в минуту обновляю сессию из БД

Comment: Зря MyISAM выбрали - она блокируется на вставку, чем больше будет таблица, тем медленнее будет все работать, плюс масса запросов будет ожидать освобождение заблокированной таблицы. MySQL  - это old school база данных - в ней нет неблокирующих проверок сокета. Поэтому каждый запрос будет занимать одно соединение, а на обслуживание других будет оставаться меньше соединений. Чем дольше соединения будут ждать (а таблица за запись блокируется полностью), тем меньше соединений будет оставаться. Оно поработает, но если будет тяжко, рассмотрите все-таки возможность использования InnoDB.

Comment: Но судя по конфигу у в вас все нормально, с 32Гб на борту, вы и 1000 соединений должны выдержать, хотя лучше так радикально параметры не изменять.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю еще раз про InnoDB, та наверное очищать будем переходы по ссылкам и показывать переходы за сутки или в поле писать это кол-во